# Explain RDD recomputation

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading about spark and came across following statement.

> Finally, Spark’s RDDs are by default recomputed each time you run an
>   action on them. If you would like to reuse an RDD in multiple actions,
>   you can ask Spark to persist it using RDD.persist()

I want to understand in detail, whats implication of re computation. For example I wrote below code snippet. I thought maybe if I add n records in text file(through terminal) while code is sleeping I will be able to see new total counts when count action is computed again. However, it just accounted for 1 additional record even if I added 3 records. *Can you help me understand above line about re computation and also if possible why my experiment does not work?*

Here is what output looks like( I have removed unnecessary lines):

Count before echo: 5

Starting sleep

11      45     225 /Users/user/data/wordCount.txt

After sleep

Count after echo: 6

```
package sparkPractice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        SparkConf conf=new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("Line Count");

        JavaSparkContext ctx=new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> textLoadRDD = ctx.textFile("/Users/user/data/wordCount.txt");
        System.out.println("Count before echo: "+textLoadRDD.count());
        System.out.println("Starting sleep");
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = rt.exec("wc /Users/user/data/wordCount.txt");
        process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line=reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {    
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println("After sleep");
        System.out.println("Count after echo: "+textLoadRDD.count());
        ctx.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the count being the same ? I've tried in a Spark-Shell and changing my file between 2 calls to "textLoadRDD.count()" gives different results

Comment: Hi @Lordofdark I have updated question with outcome of system.out.println in terms of count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified above steps and now replaced local file with new set of records instead of adding records(as above) and it worked i.e. it gave new counts instead of old count which depicts RDD is recomputed every time call is made.

Since I am executing program in local machine there might be some issue while adding records, will update this question in case I am unable to figure out while covering advance topics. However for now hypothesis is confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

> Finally, Spark’s RDDs are by default recomputed each time you run an action on them. If you would like to reuse an RDD in multiple actions, you can ask Spark to persist it using RDD.persist()

I think that this picture from [this blog](http://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2015/10/06/spark-for-data-science/) explains it pretty well :

[image]

If you don't cache / persist anything then every time you need an output (when you call an action such as "count") the data is read from disk and the operation is done. You can cache after reading (for example) then every other operations would skip the reading and start from the data cached.

See the cache as a checkpoint in your operations : When you need an output every operation is called again until the last cached RDD (or dataset).